# How to implement comprehensions using NumPy arrays?

Tags: numpy, sympy

I have two tuples of NumPy arrays. One tuple is a permutation of the other:

```
t = (np.identity(2), np.identity(3),)
s = (np.identity(3), np.identity(2),)
```

I want a tuple that indicates the permutation:

```
tuple(s.index(matrix) for matrix in t)
```

However, this leads to a ValueError, because when NumPy compares arrays, it does so element-wise:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**Question:** How can I force NumPy to perform an `a.all()` comparison in a comprehension?

**Note:** this is not a problem in SymPy. The following returns `(1, 0)`, as expected:

```
t = (sp.eye(2), sp.eye(3),)
s = (sp.eye(3), sp.eye(2),)
tuple(s.index(matrix) for matrix in t)
```

Comment: This looks like a massive XY problem. I.e., there is likely a much more suitable approach that's not O(n^3). Why are you doing this?

Comment: There's more than a simple missing `all`.  `index` is comparing `matrix` with each element of `s`.  It first tries an `is` test.  Failing that it tries `==`.  If they match in shape you get the boolean matrix, and if they differ in shape you get a DeprecationWarning.  Comparing arrays that can differ in shape is not a good idea.

Comment: Also note that in general numpy matrices contain floats, which can be almost-but-not-exactly equal due to precision loss.